# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_entry_point' (PIP)

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-3.5

How can i fix it ?
Thank you for your helps.

```
MacBook-Air:github synsx$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_entry_point'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by giving access permission to python package directory:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```